# How can I check whether 'question' in English, and 'xahesh' in Persian are cognates?

Tags: proto-indo-european, latin, persian, roots, cognates

It seems plausible to me, and I would like to know how to verify it.

Why I think *xahesh* might be cognate with *question*:

*xahesh* (IPA: /xɑːheʃ/) in Modern Persian is a noun meaning "request, plea". The root *xah-* is from the verb *xastan* /xɑːstæn/ meaning 'to want, desire'. It is spelled *xwahesh*, and was pronounced /xwɑːhesh/, as it still is in some dialects like Dari. The suffix *-esh* is from Middle Persian -eshn (/eʃn/) (or maybe -ashn) , which has essentially the same function as Latin *-tio, tionis*, turning a verb into a noun, though I'm not sure if these two are related.

Several words in Persian beginning with *xw-* appear to be derived from PIE roots beginning with *sw. For instance *xwab* (/xɑːb/, formerly /xwɑːb/) "sleep" is listed in some etymology dictionaries as a derivative of PIE *swep, cognate with Greek ὕπνος, and Latin *somnus*. Another example is *xwahar* (/xɑːhæɾ/ or /xwɑːhæɾ/) "sister", is clearly from PIE *swésōr, cognate to *sister*, *Schwester*, *soror*, etc. This does not appear to be a strict rule however, since for instance xwandan (/xɑːndæn/, /xwɑːndæn/) "to read, sing", is supposedly cognate with Latin *canō, canere*, from PIE *kan, which is not labialized.

Given that Latin *quaero* is rhotacized *quaeso*, which resembles the h/s counterpart of *xwah-*, and has a similar sense to it, I think it's reasonable to guess that the two may be cognates, but I've not been able to find this written down anywhere.

Now, this is almost certainly because I don't know where to look. I'd appreciate a response pointing out what is the right academic source or procedure for verifying such guesses. For instance, are there standard academic references for looking up the PIE roots of Persian/Iranian words?

Comment: Cheung 2007 http://dictionaries.brillonline.com/search and perhaps Mayrhofer 1986-2001 Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Altindoarischen

Comment: Definitely the origin of the word question started not from PIE s- but from PIE k^w-

Comment: It seems somewhat possible at first glance. According to Wikipedia, Iranian did have a sound change k > x in some conditions, and also a sound change s > h. I'm not sure why the /w/ would be there, though, because Iranian is supposed to have lost the labialization of the PIE labialized velars.

Comment: @Anixx: That's right. The kwo words don't have a consistent fate in Persian though. For instance there's *ki* /kiː/ meaning "who", and *chand* /tʃænd/ meaning 'how much/how many'. Possibly they both have the same PIE root *kwo* as *quaerere*. It seems plausible to me that some of these *kw- words end up as *xw-.

Comment: @sumelic: That's also puzzling to me, since the common xw- I mentioned is indeed a labialized phoneme (couldn't type a superscript here), and words like *xwahar* look to have retained that original labialization, despite what is supposed to have happened.

Comment: I think finding out the source of the /w/ sound should make things clearer. Perhaps  an excrescent /w/ developed before some vowels at some point in the history of Persian. I will try to do more research.

Comment: Words like "ki" and "chand" apparently don't have the same root as "question", by the way (but "xahesh" might). "Ki" and "chand" clearly descend from the PIE interrogative or relative pronoun, *kʷis (cognates in Latin, qui and quam). However, the word "question", despite it's apparent similarity in meaning, is not considered to derive from this root in any etymology I can find.

Comment: @sumelic how do u put superscript here?

Comment: @Anixx: Oh, I just copied and pasted that word from Wiktionary. The superscript w in it is the distinct Unicode codepoint rather than a variant of lowercase w. I don't know if we have any real superscript codes that can be used in comments.

Comment: Here is a potential answer: the Persian *xwahesh* from PIE *sweh₂d-u- "sweet", through Avestan *xʷāsta* "?", cognate with Sanskrit *svādu* "tasteful", which would make it related to *persuade* in English, and not *question*. This is stated as fact in a book of Persian/PIE roots by Ali Nourai, but I'm not sure how trustworthy it is, and I can't find an Avestan dictionary online at the moment to look up *xʷāsta*.

Comment: @A-K. Avestan xʷāsta- and Skt. svādu- are correct, but *sweh₂d-u- does not account for the Sogdian and Bactrian and Armenian forms with /z/ (see my answer).

Comment: And to your other question: IE *k and *kw become Indo-Iranian *k before IE back vowels, but *č before IE front vowels. This explains the difference between ki and čand.

Comment: ....from Iranian *ka- and *či-want- respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Henning, *Das Verbum des Mittelpersischen der Turfanfragmente* (1933) p. 187 posited Iranian *xwaz, ‘wish, want’, represented by Middle and New Persian xwāh-, with long-grade present stem, the regular SW Iranian shift of /z/ to /d/, and then a specifically Persian dialect shift of /d/ to /h/.

Johnny Cheung, *Etymological dictionary of the Iranian verb* (2007), pp. 459-460 similarly posits Iranian *xṷaz, represented also by Sogdian xw(ʼ)z, Bactrian χωζ- and others, also the Armenian loanword xuzem. No non-Iranian cognates are known.

The etymology of Latin quaero, quaestio etc. is debated, but none of the proposed suggestions links up with the cited Iranian root.

Comment: _Quaero_ really means 'look for'; its involvement in pragmatics is a later development.

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure about this , but persian word khast written as khwast  , sounds similar to english word quest with exact same meaning... in middle persian (pahlavi) it is : xvāst] xāst

Comment: Similarities in two (not closely related) modern languages are not very useful, unfortunately. Sometimes they indicate that the word has been borrowed one way or the other (eg Telephone in many languages); sometimes they are coincidence. For them to be related would require that the words have gone through the same series of sound changes (or of not changing) in both languages. This is unusual, and if it has happened, then there will be many words showing the same correspondences.